# Is there a way to move files between guest and host in virtualbox?

Tags: 13.04, virtualbox

I am using virtualbox 4.2.10 for Ubuntu. I had to unzip a .7zip file so I used gust WindowsXP to unzip. But I can't find a way to get it back to host ubuntu.  Is there a way to share between gust and host easily

Comment: You didn't need to use Windows for 7zip to begin with. Install `p7zip-full` in Ubuntu, and unzip as any other zip archive.

Comment: @mikewhatever , unfortunately due to a bug I cannot install or remove or even access software.

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for Windows XP guest? The solutions on this page are for windows 7, the interface is just different enough on Windows XP that I'm not getting any luck. The original question specified Windows XP.

Answer (score 5):

You can do either of the following:

1. Create a folder on your Ubuntu host let's say "Shared"
2. Right click the folder name "Shared" and click the Share menu. Choose the option to allow others to write the directory. The verbiage  is something like that at least you get the picture.
3. Boot up your guest and browse the network. You should now be able to view the host's "Shared" folder where you can write files and vice-versa.

Another option is by following this how to:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders

Comment: After few hours trying different suggestions and lots of search, this answer saved my life. <3

Answer (score 5):

A safe and rather straightforward way to share files from a host Ubuntu and a Windows guest is to set up a network share via Samba.

1. Define a directory on the host to share (right click menu: *Sharing Options*)

   - *On first time we try to define a share we will be prompted to install the Samba network sharing applications. Do so and reboot to take effect.*

   [image]

   Choose a sensible name for your share to be displayed in the guest. Also make sure you allow file creation for this share.
2. In the Windows guest open *Places* to select *Network*:

   [image]
3. Choose your host server name (here e.g. TAKKAT-SKV22V10) and the share to open:

   [image]

   Note that the VBOXSRV share depicted here are the Virtual Box *"Shared Folders*" if defined (needs guest additions!).
4. After having entered your credentials (choose your host name and password) we will see the content of the directory from the host.

   [image]
5. We can now just copy, paste or create files there from within Windows. These files will then be stored in the shared host directory.

Comment: This worked great -- so awesome! Thanks!